# Why when choosing No it's asking twice?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exist ?",
                        "Are you sure you want to exist ?",
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
```

If i click Yes it's existing. But if i click No the message is show again and only on the second time the No take effect.

And i have a backgroundworker and a richTextView that i update. e.Cancel = true and application.exit is enough ?

Comment: You don't want to close it, but then you want to close it.  Make up your mind.

Comment: "Are you sure you want to exist ?" Geez, that's harsh.

Comment: So you're asking if the user wants to exit, and if they say "no" then you exit anyway? (i.e. via `Application.Exit();`)?

Comment: What happens when you put a break point in the code and step through it?  Doesn't that reveal what was really going on?

Comment: `And i have a backgroundworker and a richTextView that i update` <= not sure how that is relevant to closing the application? Is there more to the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your logic is not right, you need to do one of those actions and not both depending on what was picked.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit ?",
                "Are you sure you want to exit ?",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.No)
    {
      e.Cancel = true; // cancels the close action
    }
    else
      Application.Exit(); // closes the app, this might not be necessary. Just proceeding with the form close is enough UNLESS this is not the main application form

}
```

Comment: I don't think `Application.Exit()` is necessary at all. Obviously the `Form` is already closing.

Comment: @RenéVogt - unless its not the main app form. I added it to the comments though to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

If you choose "No", you cancel the current `FormClosing` event with `e.Cancel = true;`.
But then you call `Application.Exit();` anyway. So the `Form` gets closed again and `FormClosing` is raised another time.

Remove the line `Application.Exit()` and everything should work fine.